# Different Wally West?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

I read in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_West) that Wally West is the 3<sup>rd</sup> Flash. I also read that [his father is named Rudolph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_West#Allies_and_friends). This got me confused. As someone who has never read The Flash, is this some different Wally West? I mean, I thought Wally was Joe's son and therefore Iris' brother, certainly not [nephew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_West#Supporting_cast)

Comment: If you'd scroll down to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wally_West#In_other_media you could read the explanation there.

Comment: The question remains though: Is Wally West on the TV show (or will he be) Kid Flash?

Comment: How could you think Arrowverse is solely following the comics? They have greatly deviated from the comics: be it Arrow or Flash. For instance, what should you say about Jay Garrick, the first Flash of the comics? Well, in Arrowverse, he doesn't even exist, rather he was a _time-remnant_ of Hunter Zolomon.

Comment: I said I never read the comics.

Comment: @TolgaÖ.: How could we know? The series is on-going still.

Comment: Answer is : nobody knows. Whole arrowverse is too different from comics that drawing parallel is completely irrelevant. Even in comics Wally never had only one origin, he was white man once and now half  African American.  So we don't know what is going in next season , only creator knows.

Comment: Why was this question put on-hold? I didn't ask for opinions, did I?

Comment: @TolgaÖ. Until the TV shows tells us, all we can do is speculate. Which is pointless.

Comment: The point I think being made is when you read (e.g. wiki) about Flash and/or the Arrowverse, you need to read _only_ about the TV series if that is what you are concerned with. The TV series has deviated from the comics to the point that there is no real correlation. And if you are concerned with the TV verse, we can't know some of what you are asking until it is (or is not) revealed in future episodes/seasons. Hence, opinion until factually revealed, at which time your question would be moot.

Comment: @TolgaÖ.Most people here are nice. Don't let the mafias of the world get you down. I suggest checking out the [Tour](http://movies.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better idea of why this question was put on hold. Plus, you'll get another badge.

Comment: Nothing opinión based here. Plenty of interviews answers on why they made Wally black, why they made iris black, why they made Wally a brother instead of nephew, and if he's going to be a speedster (maybe/that's a secret/wink wink nudge nudge). Word of God is not opinion and this should be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Wally West on TV is not the same as either of the Wally Wests that appears in the comics; then again, neither is Iris West (who's father is named William and didn't know Barry until they were both adults).

None of the characters on the show are *exactly* like their comic counterparts -- which, by the way, there are more than one. For most major DC character, there are four "main" versions (Golden Age, Silver Age, Post-Crisis, and New 52 versions) and dozens of "alternate universe" ones. The show, like all comics-to-TV adaptations, is taking pieces of the various comics canons and using them to build their own version of the characters.

We have no idea if Wally is ever going to end up a speedster. I *seriously* doubt they will ever call him Kid Flash, or that he will end up replacing Barry as The Flash (for one thing, they're the same age, while Wally in the comics is much younger.)

Comment: That didn't stop them from making Speedy his kid sister in Arrow instead of Roy Harper. They like to mix and match things.